# What is the joke that Alfred knows in Batman Begins?

Tags: batman-begins

In Batman Begins, on his birthday, when Bruce Wayne, leaves just about his party is about to start, to save Rachel, he asks Alfred to engage the guests with a joke "Tell them that joke you know". What is the joke?

Comment: @MeatTrademark Could you tell the whole of it

Comment: What do you call it when Batman skips church? Christian Bail.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Lol, that was a nice one... I think we see more of Alfred's story telling abilities in the second movie, where he narrates the story about the rubies in Burma, or some mountain climbing expedition

Comment: Definitely. He's played brilliantly by Caine.

Comment: @Firee Many apologies. I thought I knew it, or rather had a line on it because I have the script. It is **not** in the script.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Does the script have any lines of Alfred when Bruce Wayne re-joins the party? Maybe it can give a hint of somekind, some last words of the joke... Though I don't recall the scene very well...

Comment: No. I read the heck out of it hoping to answer the question. There's no clue I can find. I'm sure the script is still readily available online if you just type "Batman Begins script" into a search engine. Surely there's a few PDFs still wobbling about on the 'net.

Comment: @AndrewMartin  Why did Bruce's date go badly? Because he has BAT breath!

Comment: How did Bruce's mum call him for tea? "Dinner dinner dinner dinner BATMAN!"

Comment: Here's another one to 'brighten your day' :-) > A week after his wife left him, Jim went out to the local watering hole. After a long evening of drinking, Jim was thrown out of the bar as usual. > On his way home he spotted a nun walking down the road. After looking at her twice he ran over and tackled her, then proceeded to beat the living daylights out of her. > Some people passing by spotted this and called the police. As the police were pulling him away in handcuffs he looked back and said, "I thought you'd be tougher than that, Batman."

Comment: @AvatarParto Haha..

Answer (score 41):

Andrew Martin's answer

> It's not a reference to a specific joke, but rather a witty line by Bruce Wayne to effectively ask his butler to entertain all the guests in his absence.

is not entirely correct.  It was actually a light ribbing of Alfred to indicate he needs a better sense of humor.  "Tell them all *that joke* you know" is meant to indicate that Alfred knows *a* joke.  A **single** joke.  It is actually unknown if he knows any jokes at all, but even if he did, I believe that information would be irrelevant to the point Bruce Wayne was making and the laugh it was supposed to elicit from the audience.

Comment: _"It was actually a light ribbing of Alfred to indicate he needs a better sense of humor"_. I don't agree with this. This is a subjective reading of a single line being presented as fact. It **could** mean that Alfred lacked humour. Or it **could** have simply been a throwaway comment by Bruce that we're all crazily over analyzing. Ultimately, without a comment from Nolan himself, we'll never know.

Comment: The same could be said about every single answer on this site that isn't supported by a direct quote from the screenwriter/director.  I feel that if you take the body of work of the 2 characters over the span of the 3 films, my assessment makes more sense than yours.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't fit, but like you said - you feel it. It's subjective. There's a difference between saying "no one knows, here's my interpretation" and saying "this is obviously what is meant".

Comment: I don't know, man.  I just looked at your answer and all the responses and it looks like Napolean agreed with me, and 3 people agreed with him.  To me, it's absolutely obvious, but again every single answer on this site is subjective if it's not backed by a direct quote.

Comment: I agree with everything you're saying. I just was commenting on the fact you presented your answer as if it were fact and thus the only "correct" interpretation, rather than being just an opinion. It was just a comment though. It's definitely a fair and plausible explanation.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: Stating that someone only knows one joke very much takes a jab at them not being comedic. Not that they _can't_ be funny, just that they usually don't joke around.

Answer (score 30):

The scene in question proceeds like this ([from the script](http://www.nolanfans.com/library/pdf/batmanbegins-screenplay.pdf)):

> Wayne hurries through the hall. Alfred in pursuit. Tables of food and
> decoration fill the hall.
>
> **ALFRED**: But Master Wayne, the guests will be
> arriving.
>
> Wayne turns.
>
> **WAYNE**: Keep them happy until I arrive. Tell them
> that joke you know.
>
> Wayne hurries off. Alfred watches him go,
> exasperated.

It's not a reference to a *specific* joke, but rather a witty line by Bruce Wayne to effectively ask his butler to entertain all the guests in his absence. There's no interviews I've come across which suggest Christopher Nolan intended it to have any greater meaning than this.

Nevertheless, this question *has* been asked over at the [Nolan Fans](http://www.nolanfans.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=12684&view=unread#unread) website and, although coming to the same conclusion, the fans came up with a few possible jokes of their own. They're fairly terrible, which makes them quite funny. Since I'm sorry to answer this question in the negative, I'll include one to brighten your day! Here goes:

> Why didn't Batman go fishing today? Because Robin ate the worms!

Comment: LoL, that was a lame joke... Well just yesterday only I saw a re-run of Batman Begins, and that it when it stuck me. Though you say its not a specific joke, but the line hints at some joke of Alfred's which is quite popular..

Comment: What does Batgirl wear to bed? Her Dark Knight gown :) I wouldn't say it hints at a specific joke. I think it's just a line showing how easy, calm and collect Bruce is compared to Alfred's more worrying nature. You COULD argue it's a cheeky dig, suggesting the joke is so long it will take an age to tell and thus keep everyone busy for quite a while - but I really think that's reading too much into it.

Comment: @Firee I rather think the actual point of the dialogue is not to hint at a *specific* joke, but to emphasize the fact that it's only *one* single joke he knows and the funny part is that it isn't quite likely for *Alfred* to be able to entertain the whole party for a long time with just a single little joke he knows, a joke that's probably as old (or older) as *Bruce* is. That's what the *"that joke"* means, I guess, it's the same joke he probably told the people at *Thomas*'s birthday party 40 years ago.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Yes, you got it correct. My thought was also on similar lines. But the questions is, what is the joke...

Comment: The joke is ultimately irrelevant, other than for a fun piece of trivia. A great example of this would be the Three Seashells in Demolition Man, which were never explained yet provided a comic backdrop so often in the story.

Comment: @AndrewMartin One joke, Ben Affleck will be Batman one day

Comment: @Firee *"But the questions is, what is the joke..."* - But unfortunately that question is *deliberately* unanswerable (except by fan fiction).

Comment: @AndrewMartin Sandra Bullock has given us [the answer](http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1715032/sandra-bullock-demolition-man-seashells.jhtml).
Exiting a bathroom Stallone asks why there's no toilet paper, and only 3 seashells on a shelf. "He doesn't know how to use the three seashells!" says Rob Schneider. And they all laugh. We never found out how the 3 seashells are used.

Josh Horowitz asked Bullock to settle the mystery.

"Well, think of a bidet, right?" said Bullock. "There's several processes. You have number one, you have number two, and then the cleanup." (The link is more thorough.)