# Is there a reference\nod in the line "Much more subtle"?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight, reference

In *The Dark Knight*, Bruce Wayne tells Alfred he's going to a place. Alfred asks about taking a batmobile. Bruce says it is day now and he going to take another vehicle. Alfred then says, "Oh Lamborghini then, much more subtle". Why is he saying that? Is there any reference or citation that I missed?

Comment: He's saying a very expensive Lamborghini isn't subtle at all. If it's a reference, I can't recall it (maybe Bond?). I think there's a similar line in *Iron Man*, but it came out around the same time (summer 2008).

Comment: It's a sarcastic joke

Comment: Lamborghinis aren't subtle, but they're more subtle than a batmobile. Like @Huangism says, it's a sarcastic joke.

Comment: It's the [joke that Alfred knows](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/what-is-the-joke-that-alfred-knows-in-batman-begins)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lamborghini's cost hundreds of thousands of dollars.  Everyone (or **most** everyone) knows this.  They're not as common as a Toyota or a Chevrolet.  As such, when one is passing by you will almost certainly notice.

This was a bit of sarcasm by Alfred, as both modes of transportation (Batmobile vs Lamborghini) are definitely head-turners and will not go unnoticed.